# Calling Firebase.initializeApp() returns 'Unable to establish connection on channel' - Flutter + Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm working with Firebase in flutter (latest versions as of 1st July 2022), and when I try to call Firebase.initializeApp() in my Main function, it returns an error of:

```
'[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)'
```

Here is my code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which operating system are you using? According to the [pub.dev package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) it only supports `iOS`, `Android`, `macOS`, and `Web`.

Comment: @lepsch, thanks for the reply, I am using Android currently

Comment: Facing same issue, found nothing helpful so far.

Comment: Also, correct this `Firebase.initializeApp();`, it should be `await Firebase.initializeApp();`.

Comment: Everyone's facing the same problem for the past 7-8 hours. See the bug filed on Flutter's repo [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9022), this community issue [here](https://community.flutterflow.io/c/discuss-and-get-help/getting-blank-white-screen-on-local-device)..

Comment: This error is KILLING me! Have been trying to fix it for 3 days now! Have tried everything listed below, nothing works! About to throw my laptop out the window! Worst thing is iOS runs just fine, its only Android causing this error. Shoot me.

Comment: My device wasn't connected to the internet ‍♂️

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by upgrading all my firebase dependencies to the latest version using `flutter pub outdated` and `flutter pub upgrade firebase_...`.

I encountered this issue after adding the `firebase_messaging` plugin v11.4.4. Might be related to the change in `firebase_core_platform_interface`.

Comment: Solved it for me.  Looks like the root of my problem was upgrading a Firebase dependency for a library, but not upgrading the rest of the firebase dependencies at the top level of the project.

Answer (score 13):

Also got it after a pub update. Fixed it by doing:
`flutter clean`
and removing the pubspec.lock

Answer (score 7):

I have updated the below dependency:

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.4.1
```

Executed this command and updated firebase dependencies

`flutter pub upgrade firebase_core`

`flutter pub upgrade firebase_messaging`

it is working properly now.

Answer (score 6):

Do a flutter clean and upgrade firebase core with

```
    flutter pub upgrade firebase_core
```

The run

```
    dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
    flutterfire configure
```

to reinitialize firebase. I experienced this after adding app_check support

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be with the core platform interface.
Add firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.4.0 and adjust all other firebase deps to make them compatible with this library. I downgraded all versions to 36 day old release and it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

I just built a new flutter app and I got this error when initializing Firebase App and running it in the browser and not the android emulator.  I am using VS Code and you can change the target device in the bottom task bar on the right side.

Solution is to run it in the android emulator. I don't know if there are permissions to be set for web view but I do not plan on deploying to web.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I started a new project and I only enabled the phone auth provider and did not enable the email provider first. So make sure that both email and phone providers are enabled in the firebase settings.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was passing empty arguments, so check your arguments

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and scaled back (thank you git) - getting flutter dependencies right - as in it compiles *and* work as advertised is no mean feat. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_auth: '4.3.0'
  firebase_auth_platform_interface: '6.15.3'
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly causing the issue. But I do it like first doing `flutter clean` and upgrading my all Firebase dependencies. You can hit `flutter pub outdated` it will see the outdated dependencies and then you can do `flutter pub upgrade` your dependency name e.g. `flutter pub upgrade firebase_auth`.

The interesting part is that even after all I was also having the following issues as:
**[firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel.** then I realized the empty email and password field was causing an error. Just filled that and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check for this Error :

- `Check your dependencies in pubspec.yaml`
- `Check if the email or password fields is not empty`

In my case I was passing `Empty Strings` for `Email` and `Password` fields causing this Error, You can **Print** the values when you are passing for authentication.