# Flutter: Firebase.initializeApp() throws PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am having an issue where my project runs fine on iOS, but on Android I get the following error:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))
```

Complete stack here:

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(19624): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51576/EjKjPfki7E8=/ws
E/flutter (19624): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
E/flutter (19624): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:199
E/flutter (19624): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19624): #1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29
E/flutter (19624): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19624): #2      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73
E/flutter (19624): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19624): #3      Firebase.initializeApp
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40
E/flutter (19624): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19624): #4      main
package:cadsys_adm/main.dart:11
E/flutter (19624): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19624):
```

And the code causing the error is:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I'm only using two Firebase packages (from pubspec.yaml):

```
  firebase_core: ^1.19.2
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.3
```

A similar question exists here, but none of the fixes work for me: [Calling Firebase.initializeApp() returns 'Unable to establish connection on channel' - Flutter + Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833245/calling-firebase-initializeapp-returns-unable-to-establish-connection-on-chan/73445288?noredirect=1#comment129701893_73445288)

Has anyone come across any fix for this? Remember, it occurs ONLY on Android, not on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

it happens when this code
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
Firebase.initializeApp();

is written  if i uncomment it it works fine
however  i am tired of it
but as i mentioned it does not creat any problem in android studio

even it does not solved by
changing the version of dependency in pubspec.yaml

not even by

flutter pub upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get

these are not the real solutions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your anwser isn't an answer, if you don't have a correct answer to the question, please don't post as an anwers rather in a comment. thank u!

Comment: How would you use Firebase without initializing it?? Of course removing that line "fixes" it, since you are not using it?