iOS - PlatformException - Unable to establish connection on channel
I know this topic has been discussed before, but I've tried everything, wiped all the plasters and I still have the same problem. I'm stuck. If anyone has a new lead?
I recreated the ios folder, restarted, upgraded, I'm connected from XCode on my Apple developer account, on the Firebase side I checked the accesses 10 times, the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file is in the Runner folder.
I've run the commands many times: flutter clean, flutter pub get, in ios: pod install and flutter build ios...
My goal : receive notifications (Push notifications)
Error when calling this method, from main.dart :
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
When I DEBUG the mobile app, the DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform variable does indeed contain the settings from my GoogleService-Info.plist file
Error :
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:210:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:66:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      main (package:imin/main.dart:21:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

flutter -v doctor : 
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 3.24.4 on channel stable at /Users/doandgo/Desktop/Programmation/GitHub/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 603104015d (2 weeks ago), 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
    • Engine revision db49896cf2
    • Dart version 3.5.4
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/doandgo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/doandgo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16B40
    • CocoaPods version 1.16.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/doandgo/Desktop/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.100.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone doandgo (mobile) • 00008030-001A054A2289802E • ios            • iOS 17.5.1 21F90
    • macOS (desktop)         • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.117

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

flutter pub outdated:
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.
If I remove the following call from main.dart:
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
I modified the AppDelegate.swift:
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   var window: UIWindow?

   func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

       FirebaseApp.configure()

       // Demander l'autorisation pour les notifications
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
           print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
       }

       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

       return true
   }
  
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
       print("Device Token: \(deviceToken)")
       // Send device token to server
   }
  
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
       print("Failed to register: \(error)")
   }
}

I have this error :
11.4.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001011] App Delegate Proxy is disabled.
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.11.4.0 started
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS025036] App Delegate Proxy is disabled
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS044002] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly.
Permission granted: true
Device Token: 32 bytes
flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://0.0.0.0:50189/0bnRLGk1AZs=/
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
11.4.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [...]) to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:195:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:79:41)
#2      FirebaseMessaging.instance (package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:32:47)
#3      _MyAppState.setupInteractedMessage (package:imin/main.dart:50:33)
…
#112    Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
#113    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
#114    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
#115    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method read on channel plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      SecureStorageNotifier.getValue (package:imin/domain/provider/secure_storage_provider.dart:29:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      SecureStorageNotifier.getCountryCode (package:imin/domain/provider/secure_storage_provider.dart:33:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _LoginSessionState._initSessionFromStorage (package:imin/presentation/login/login_session_widget.dart:28:9)
<asynchronous suspension>

I have run the following commands many times: flutter clean, flutter pub get, in ios: pod install and flutter build ios…
When I DEBUG the mobile app, the DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform variable contains the settings of my GoogleService-Info.plist file
I have recreated the ios folder, restarted, upgraded, I am connected from XCode to my Apple developer account, on the Firebase side I have checked the accesses 10 times, the “GoogleService-Info.plist” file is in the Runner folder. I have run the following commands many times: flutter clean, flutter pub get, in ios: pod install and flutter build ios…

The problem look like very difficult, nobody answered :) I think that the problem is localised when i add a code for manage the reception of messages in AppDelegate.swift . I think that is the call application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833245/calling-firebase-initializeapp-returns-unable-to-establish-connection-on-chan
